# Stop my app from being updated(auto-update is disabled)

Tags: android

Consider that user has my app with version 1 and auto update option is disabled/off. I have an upgrade in the market for my app(say version 2). 
User gets a notification saying, "updates available" and updates my app.
Now based on some requirement I need my app not be be upgraded to version 2.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very odd question...
It can't be done, since the application WILL be updated to the new one when the user UPDATES the application as this is the concept of updating the app...
You can, however, do these differentiations in the code, where if you don't want the new updated code to occur, just call the old one... Then you'll have 2 sets of logics inside your code and you will run the correct code based on your decision

Comment: thnks a lot for the quick reply..
Consider that there are two apps App-A and App-B.App-A(Version 1) will work only if App-B with Version 1 is available on phone.Now if the user updates App-B to version 2,the App-A(version-1) will not work.I get a callback once App-B is upgraded to version2, once upgraded i cannot revert back to version-1 apk of App-B. Instead can I stop my App-B from being upgraded to version 2 and probably show a notification to user saying that this version of App-B is not compatible.
As you said one way is to maintain two sets of logic, is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: You can add logic to App-A that says that if App-B's version is bigger than App-A's version, you don't let the user use the app until he updates App-A as well.