# Prevent application from updating

Tags: android

Is it possible to restrict an application from updating ? I'd like to disable receiving update messages from GooglePlay from the application code itself.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305162/stop-my-app-from-being-updatedauto-update-is-disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to restrict an application from updating ?

Do not publish any updates. Otherwise, no, all users of your app have the right to all updates to that app that you publish.

Comment: offtopic: could you look here please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490982/slow-preparation-on-android-2-2-mediaplayer-use-previous-version